# Simple module with non-simple restriction.

Tags: modules, representation-theory

If $G$ is a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$, would it be possible to have a simple $\mathbb{C}G$-module $V$ for which the restriction $\operatorname{Res}^G_HV$ is not a simple $\mathbb{C}H$-module? What would be examples of such a behaviour?

Comment: More or less every triple $(G,H,V)$ satisfies this. For example, any simple module of dimension greater than $1$ and any abelian subgroup.

Comment: Okay, lets say $V$ is an irreducible $\mathbb{C}G$-module with $dim(V)=2$ for example. Now lets say $H$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$. We can consider $H$ as  a $\mathbb{C}H$-module. Since $dim(V)>1$ we can decompose it in two vector spaces $V=V_1\oplus V_2$. But why are they submodules? If $v_1\in V_1$, do we necessarily have $h\cdot v_1\in V_1$?

Comment: All simple modules for abelian groups are $1$-dimensional. Not all subspaces are submodules. But they are there somewhere.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If we take for $H$ the trivial subgroup of $G$ then the restriction $\operatorname{Res}^G_H V$ is simple if and only if $V$ is one-dimensional.
In this way every simple $\mathbb{C}G$-module of dimension at least two gives a counterexample.